# WPF Button click has no references

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button inside a `Grid` container that is inside a `ScrollViewer` Container.
When I double click the button to auto fill the button click code in c# I get no references.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="_scroll">
            <Grid Height="584">
                <Button x:Name="n_one" Content="N" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Height="23"/>
            </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

There is more stuff in the Grid `Container` but they are just labels and buttons. They other elements in the container aren't suffering from the same issue.

```
private void n_one_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working")
}
```

I do have the Console setup and working shown with previous code. Visual Studio is telling me i have 0 references to `n_one_Click` why is this?

If this changes anything, I did copy this button a few times, I did rename these buttons, but they also have the same problem, elements that aren't related but still in the same container aren't affected.

Comment: I have no clue how but it now works.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the `n_one` button to fire your `n_one_Click` method, I would expect your XAML to look like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="_scroll">
    <Grid Height="584">
        <Button 
            x:Name="n_one" 
            Content="N" 
            Click="n_one_Click"  <========== Here
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="134,165,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="30" 
            FontSize="18" 
            FontWeight="Bold" 
            Height="23"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: yeah thanks, just figured that out after restarting then, trying again it generated that field.